# EF Core Deleting related entities on One To One relationship

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.1, ef-code-first-mapping

I have a one to one relationship set up on ef core. When i try to delete `Article`
entity I need to cascade `MediPlan` since it is `one to one` relationship. When I Delete `Article`, `MediaPlan` is not getting removed.

Here is set up.

```
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int MediaPlanId { get; set; }

    public MediaPlan MediaPlan { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class MediaPlan
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Article Article { get; set; }
}
```

Context

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().HasOne(x => x.MediaPlan).WithOne(x => x.Article);
```

Code to delete

```
var article = await _db.Articles
            .Include(x=>x.MediaPlan)
            .SingleAsync(x=>x.Id == id);
_db.Articles.Remove(article);
await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Do I have to set a FK on `MediaPlan` entity as well?

Thank you!

Comment: Cascaded delete deletes *children*, i.e. the records that contain the FK field. In this case, an Article is deleted cascading when a `MediaPlan` is deleted. You can't have it both ways. If you want it the other way around you must make `MediaPlan` refer to `Article` by FK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your `One-to-One` *Fluent API* configuration is not written in correct way as you did not specify the dependent entity. Your *Fluent API* configuration should be written as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().HasOne(a => a.MediaPlan)
                              .WithOne(mp => mp.Article)
                              .HasForeignKey<Article>(a => a.MediaPlanId)
                              .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Now deleting a `MediaPlan` will also delete its dependent `Article` as follows:

```
var mediaPlanToBeDeleted = await _db.MediaPlans.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=>x.Id == id);
_db.MediaPlans.Remove(mediaPlanToBeDeleted);
await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Now if you want the reverse behavior then you have to reverse your *Fluent API* configuration.

*Note: Only deleting the principal entity will cascade delete the dependent entity. Vice-versa is not possible.*

Comment: Thank you. In this case what would be principle?

Comment: MediaPlan is principle and Article is dependent.